# unexpected error Errno::EACCES error=Permission denied EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, td-agent

When I am trying to collect yarn logs using td-agent i am getting this exception in td-agent log .

The td-agent is installed in root

unexpected error error_class=Errno::EACCES error="Permission denied @ rb_file_s_stat - /var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1540322839807_0001/container_1540322839807_0001_01_000001/stderr

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with td-agent also.
You can quick fix it in few ways:

- Add the td-agent user to the same group which has access over that log file.
- Run the td-agent as a root user, you need to modify this in service file.

Waiting for the tool developers to fix it.

If anyone has a simpler work around, they are also welcome to post the solution here.

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data td-agent` # This will add td-agent user to www-data group ..................

`groups td-agent` # lists all groups of td-agent user